# No .bbl file generated using TexWorks

Tags: bibtex, bbl

I'm using TexWorks to write a journal paper with citations. I have the .tex and .bib files and some figure files and use XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX to produce the .pdf document. Everything works. The references are displayed correctly. But my TexWorks only produces the .pdf and .synctex.gz files. The .bbl file, as required by arXiv, is not generated. My TeXworks version is 0.6.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit). How do I enable my TeXworks to generate the .bbl file?

An example of my .tex file is given below:

```
\documentclass[aps, superscriptaddress, showpacs, floatfix, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
\title{The title of the paper} 
\author{George}
\affiliation{My affiliation}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract of the paper.
\end{abstract}

\pacs{pacs numbers}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The paper \cite{paper} has done some previous work.

\bibliography{abc_refs}
\end{document}
```

The .bib file:

```
@article{paper,
  author = {George},
  journal = {Journal name},
  volume = {12},
  issue = {3},
  pages = {45--67},
  year = {1234},
}
```

It looks like TexWorks directly generates .pdf without .bbl. Is there an option setting that would tell TexWorks to generate the .bbl file?

Comment: The extensions are shown. I only have 2 output files with extensions .pdf and .synctex.gz. Not sure how to get other output files generated and I need the .bbl file.

Comment: Check if in the settings of  the profile in texworks there is the --clean option and remove it.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I managed to generate the intermediate files by doing the typesetting commands XeLaTeX, MakeIndex, and BibTeX separately. The automated typesetting command XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX only produces the .pdf and .synctex.gz files.

Answer (score 0):

George's method of running the typesetting commands separately works for me. However, I found that running pdfLaTeX separately ruins the cross-references. So I did this in this order and it worked:

1. Run pdfLaTeX  separately to generate auxiliary files
2. Run BibTeX separately to generate .bbl file
3. Run pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX to generate pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for sharing something that worked for you, but did you mean for your last one in `3.` to be pdfLaTeX or did you run BibTeX again? I don't think running BibTeX would do anything when run last, could you clarify please

Comment: I wonder if what you actually need for 3. is the double `pdflatex` compilation, after running `bibtex`, one `pdflatex` compilation is required to incorporate the bibliography and create new labels, then a second `pdflatex` is needed to update all the cross-references in line with the new labels.